# How to create a method to return matching values in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm new to programming and I am trying to teach myself some basic coding skills.

I have started experimenting with arrays and would like to solve the following task:

> Create a method which returns all matching values from two arrays and display those matching values in the console.

So far I’ve only got as far as creating two arrays, `list1` and `list2`. I believe I need to use a for or a while loop to find the matching values in each array but I am unsure of how to do this and then what I need to do next.

Can someone give me some advice please?

So far this is what I’ve written:

```
package project1;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int list1 [] = {1,2,55,8,7,9,60,4};
    int list2 [] = {3,12,1,71,4,6,1,10};
    }

}
```

Comment: please share your effort?

Comment: Declaring the arrays isn't exactly what we mean when we say "show some effort before asking a question". You have to actually try to solve the task.

Comment: that's what tutorials are used for, not SO. Please remove the question

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you have to create a loop to read an array.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list1 [] = {1,2,55,8,7,9,60,4};
        int list2 [] = {3,12,1,71,4,6,1,10};

        for (int i=0;i<list1.length;i++){
        System.out.println(list[i]);
//If you want to print any specific position put the position of the array that you want to print (taking into account that arrays start in 0 position):
  System.out.println(list[0]);
        }
        for (int j=0;i<list2.length;j++){
        System.out.println(list[j]);
        }

    }
```

Those simply two loops creates an integer called `i` and `j` which initially has value 0. In every loop, you will print every position of your arrays until i and j reaches the length of the array (`list1.length` and `list2.length`). When the loop prints the first position, those integers increments their value in one (`i++ and j++`) and prints the next position.

Comment: Thanks for this. This does works fine but my intention is to find and print only the numbers that occur in both list1 and list2. So in my example only the number 1 should be printed

Comment: what you provided prints every number in both arrays

Comment: Then change i variable to the position that you want to print. Answer edited @bobe_b

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following code and try to understand it. Refer the java documentation or if you're using an IDE like eclipse, hover your mouse on functions to get a description about the functionality.

```
public static void getMatchingElements(int[] array1, int[] array2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {

            if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                System.out.println(array1[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The above algorithm is a very simple one. Hope you can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int list1 [] = {1,2,55,8,7,9,60,4};
    int list2 [] = {3,12,1,71,4,6,1,10};

    for(int x : list1){
        if(Arrays.asList(list2).contains(x)){
            System.out.println( x + " : present in second array.");
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get it now. You want to print out the values that exist both in list1 and list2. Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int list1 [] = {1,2,55,8,7,9,60,4};
        int list2 [] = {3,12,1,71,4,6,1,10};
        getMatchingValues(list1,list2);
    }
    public static void getMatchingValues(int[] list1, int[] list2)
    {
        for(int value1 : list1)
        {
            for(int value2 : list2)
            {
                if(value1==value2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Both lists contain "+value1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should note though, number 4 also satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Many thanks for you help Oshyrath. Thats exactly what i wanted to do :) I dont fully understand it but i will spend soem time experimenting with it now to get a full understanding of what each part does. Thanks again! :)

Comment: okay so the following lines of code im having trouble understanding....for(int value1 : list1)

Comment: Basically, it's called an enhanced for loop. The loop passes once for each value in list1. Every pass, value1 is the next value located in the list. Ex, the first pass, value1 will be 1, then 2, then 55, then 8, and so on.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks for the explanation and for your help Oshyrath!